# How to check/uncheck radio button in a modal via mysql data?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

This is how I send data from button to the MODAL. This works perfectly.

```
echo "<td><button type='button' class='btn btn-danger' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#MORMODALTRANSFER' data-id='".$row['MORID']."'>More on this... </button></td>";
```

This is how I bind the data to the MODAL, works perfectly.

```
$('#myMODAL').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
var ID = button.data('id') 
modal.find('.modal-body #IDq').val(ID)
```

This is the radio button on a modal im trying to check

```
<div class="form-group">
                                <label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="r2"class="minimal-red" value="noncomp">A
                                </label>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="r2" class="minimal-red"value="comp">B
                                </label>
                                <label>
                                  <input type="radio" name="r3"class="minimal-red"value="nonconf">
                                  C
                                </label>
                                <label>
                                <input type="radio" name="r3"class="minimal-red"value="conf">
                                 D
                                </label>                                    
                              </div>
```

I'm fully aware of binding and using the data on a MODAL when dealing with textfields however, My question is, How to bind the data to a set of radio buttons ?

Comment: I don't see any `radio button` and `mysql` data in your code

Comment: By radio button name. When button is clicked, get radio button checked value and pass it to modal. You wont be taking data from button but from radio button instead since that value is not fixed.

Comment: @JYoThI added code.

Comment: @Spectarion yes that's the idea. But the syntax is what I'm not sure of. To emphasize, i'll get the value from mysql, send it to the button, then send it to the modal from the button. In the modal, based on the data I intend to check/uncheck. The syntax of this is a mystery to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check below code that might help you. Comment if any further explanation required.

```js
$('#myMODAL').on('show.bs.modal', function(event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget); // Button that triggered the modal
  $('input[name="optradio"]:checked').prop('checked', false); //I'm doing this coz every time new popup opens redio button will be reset to none. If you don't need to do this remove this line
  var ID = button.data('id');
  $('input[name="optradio"][value="'+ID+'"]').prop('checked',true);
});
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL">Open Modal - Check None</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL" data-id="10">Open Modal - Check 10</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL" data-id="11">Open Modal - Check 11</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL" data-id="12">Open Modal - Check 12</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL" data-id="13">Open Modal - Check 13</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL" data-id="14">Open Modal - Check 14</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myMODAL" data-id="15">Open Modal - Check 15</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myMODAL" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="10">10</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="11">11</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="12">12</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="13">13</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="14">14</label>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
          <label><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="15">15</label>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It did work somewhat for me. What happens is the item seemed to be checked however the "check mark" isn't there. When I check the other buttons it checks but the item to be checked is disabled indicating that it's checked but there's no check mark.

Comment: Solved the issue by removing the style.